# Tamper or Tamper with. Which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Why do we need to say "He tampered with the ball" than just saying he tampered the ball?

Comment: Because **tamper** is not a simple transitive like "kick" or "throw", but an action that *involves* an object.  We do not *mess the ballots* but *mess with the ballots*. The ballots are instrumental in our messing.

Comment: In short: because that's how the verb *tamper* is used.

Comment: *Tamper with* is the phrasal verb.  *Tamper* by itself is a noun.

Comment: @Andrew tamper is both verb and noun.

Comment: After reading above comments, I got the idea as such that we say "tampered with" as we are working on the object i.e. on the ball and not working with the object.

Comment: @Gt_R  Technically "tamper" by itself is *considered* a verb, but when actually *used* as a verb, it never appears without "with".   So "tamper" by itself or when combined with another word (*tamper-proof*) is probably considered some other part of speech.

Comment: @Andrew Hm, maybe *tamper with* is a phrasal verb, but I don't think it is, or that that matters. It's just that it's commonly used together with *with* to introduce the object. It means nothing different from just *tamper*. E.g., you can talk about (just) *tampering*, but you could also add *...with evidence*.

Comment: @userr2684291  I expect if we got one of the linguistic pros involved there would be a long discussion of what *exactly* they'd call it because it's such a unique animal.  But that's probably a separate question.

Comment: @Andrew I thought a phrasal verb is a verb + adverb paring (e.g. "let's get down and boogie") where a prepositional verb is a verb + preposition (e.g. "antibiotics can help you get over an infection").

Comment: @m_a_s  according to [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs) it's an umbrella term that covers both.  But as I said earlier I'm sure the pros on ELL would have their own opinions, and I don't have that kind of scholarship.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositional verbs need a preposition and an object to follow the verb.  The British Council's Learn English website [has a short explanation of this.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/verbs-prepositions)

You "break into a car"
Someone "deals with a situation"
They had to "do without food"

Tamper is such a verb.  See the M-W [definition of tamper](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tamper).  Note how it specifically calls out its use with "with" in the definitions:

> a : to interfere so as to weaken or change for the worse —used with with "did not want to tamper with tradition"
>   b : to try foolish or dangerous experiments —used with with
>   c : to render something harmful or dangerous by altering its structure or composition "was charged with tampering with consumer products"